# javascript onblur / onfocus with iframe not working issues

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onblur, onfocus

I use onblur and onfocus function in my page.
But also, I use a iframe into page.
And my problem is onblur and andfocus functions not working  together into page if I use a iframe.

I clicked in iframe when onblur function is working.But I dont want this function work if I clicked in iframe. I want to  run only work it if user will change browser tab

if I will use hasFocus function and users changes browser tab , this time onblur is not working

my js codes:

```js
var after_title = 'Back to page';
var dafault_title = document.title;
var deg;
window.onblur = function () { document.title = after_title; beep(); deg=setTimeout(check,2000); }
window.onfocus = ()=>(deg)?clearTimeout(deg):null;
function beep() {
var snd = new  Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,//uQRAAAAWMSLwUIYAAsYU=");
    snd.play();
}
function check()
{
    if(document.hasFocus()){
        document.title = dafault_title;
        return;
    }else{
        location.href = './index.php';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>default page<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<iframe id="abc" name="abc" frameborder="1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" framespacing="0" width="100px" height="100px">
<p>example include page</p>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to react to tabchange, don't use the `blur` and `focus` events, but rather the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) instead:

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) { // equivalent to "blur"
    document.title = after_title; beep(); deg=setTimeout(check,2000);
  } else  { // equivalent to "focus"
    if (deg) {
      clearTimeout(deg);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```